# Why this code gives me error?

Tags: python

```
def rpsls(name): 
    '''
(string) -> string
This  function find and print Player choice by 
name and computer choise by random number and
who wins according to scope.if player enter wrong
number return  error message

'''





# convert name to player_number using name_to_number
player_number = name_to_number(name)

# compute random guess for comp_number using random.randrange()
comp_number = random.randrange(0,5)

# compute difference of player_number and comp_number modulo five
compute_difference = (player_number - comp_number) % 5

# use if/elif/else to determine winner
if compute_difference > 2:
    winner = "computer wins"
elif compute_difference == '':
    winner = ''
elif compute_difference == 0:
    winner = 'player and computer tie!'
else:
    winner = "player wins"
# convert comp_number to name using number_to_name
comp_name = number_to_name(comp_number)
# print results
if winner == '':
    print "try again"
else:
    print ''
    print 'Player chooses '+ name
    print 'computer chooses '+ comp_name
    print winner
```

I don't know why but this code not working . it said to be here is the problem accured. i wannted it to be clear. please help me.this is a assignment .but its already over and i counldn't finish it

Comment: Please show us the error message!

Comment: where did u define name_to_number?? please show the error message?

Comment: Aside from `number_to_name` and `name_to_number`, which aren't defined, everything runs fine (in python 2.6 -- in python 3.* it'd break on every print since it's a function there and needs parentheses)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go an answer to the whole program: 
Rock-paper-scissors-lizard-Spock template
`import random`

The key idea of this program is to equate the strings
 "rock", "paper", "scissors", "lizard", "Spock" to numbers
 as follows:

0 - rock
 1 - Spock
 2 - paper
 3 - lizard
4 - scissors

helper functions

```
def number_to_name(number):
# fill in your code below

# convert number to a name using if/elif/else
# don't forget to return the result!
    if number == 0:
        return 'rock'
    elif number == 1:
        return 'Spock'
    elif number == 2:
        return 'paper'
    elif number == 3:
        return 'lizard'
    elif number == 4:
        return 'scissors'


def name_to_number(name):
# fill in your code below

# convert name to number using if/elif/else
# don't forget to return the result!
    if name == 'rock':
        return 0
    elif name == 'Spock':
        return 1
    elif name == 'paper':
        return 2
    elif name == 'lizard':
        return 3
    elif name == 'scissors':
        return 4

def rpsls(name):
# fill in your code below

# convert name to player_number using name_to_number
    player_number = name_to_number(name)
# compute random guess for comp_number using random.randrange()
    comp_number = random.randrange(5)
# compute difference of player_number and comp_number modulo five
    difference = (player_number - comp_number) % 5
# use if/elif/else to determine winner
    if difference in [1, 2]:
        winmsg = "Player wins!"
    elif difference == 0:
        winmsg = "Player and computer tie!"
    else:
        winmsg = "Computer wins!"
# convert comp_number to name using number_to_name
    comp_name = number_to_name(comp_number)
# print results
    print " "
    print "Player chooses " + str(name)
    print "Computer chooses " + str(comp_name)
    print winmsg
```

test your code

```
rpsls("rock")
rpsls("Spock")
rpsls("paper")
rpsls("lizard")
```

Comment: holly cow the import random . thanks my friend

Comment: I'm sure this answered the question, but I'm also sure it devaluates the value of Coursera courses (and if you participated in the course, goes against their code of conduct).

Comment: @Arjan I'm just trying to help.The OP said " already over and i counldn't finish it"Now that I answered the OP's question,he/she can look at the answer and try to learn from it.Also the Coursera Course is already over,so the OP is doing self study,and providing some help is not a problem.Has the course been in progress,then my answer would have violated Coursera's second Honor Code(which says,"My answers to homework,quizzes and exams will be my own work (except for assignments that explicitly permit collaboration)"assuming the OP submitted my answer as theirs,but the course is not in progress.

Comment: Coursera courses are often repeated. And even without that fact and what I wrote above, I feel it's not helping anyone to just post the complete assignment. Better let hints being given in the Coursera forum. (But then, the question was bad too, and has now been closed, so I'll just hope it gets deleted.)

Comment: @Arjan I hope so too.Yeah you're right.I should've gave hints.Anyways the the question is closed now.